# Error importing spatial data in GeoDjango - KeyError for mpoly field

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, geodjango

I was following the tutorial on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#importing-spatial-data for setting up GeoDjango on my machine. But it seems like there is some issue there. While importing data using LayerMapping by running `load.run()`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/src/django/world/load.py", line 23, in run
    lm = LayerMapping(WorldBorder, world_shp, world_mapping, transform=False, encoding='iso-8859-1')
  File "/home/ubuntu/Envs/vir-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/utils/layermapping.py", line 105, in __init__
    self.check_layer()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Envs/vir-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/utils/layermapping.py", line 178, in check_layer
    ogr_field_types = self.layer.field_types
  File "/home/ubuntu/Envs/vir-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/layer.py", line 153, in field_types
    for i in range(self.num_fields)]
KeyError: 12
```

Then I found out that, there is no 'MULTIPOLYGON' field in the `.shp` file:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.gdal import DataSource
>>> ds = DataSource('world/data/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp')
>>> layer = ds[0]
>>> layer.fields
[u'FIPS', u'ISO2', u'ISO3', u'UN', u'NAME', u'AREA', u'POP2005', u'REGION', u'SUBREGION', u'LON', u'LAT']
```

But it's there in the `WorldBorder` model, as type `MultiPolygonField`.
So, definitely in the world_mapping file, importing will fail for the `'mpoly': 'MULTIPOLYGON'` mapping. Has anyone else faced this issue? I hope so, as I've followed the tutorial step-by-step. But it doesn't say anything about such issue. What effect it will have, if I load data by removing `mpoly` mapping?

Here's my load.py file:

```
  1 import os
  2 from django.contrib.gis.utils import LayerMapping
  3 from models import WorldBorder
  4
  5 world_mapping = {
  6     'fips' : 'FIPS',
  7     'iso2' : 'ISO2',
  8     'iso3' : 'ISO3',
  9     'un' : 'UN',
 10     'name' : 'NAME',
 11     'area' : 'AREA',
 12     'pop2005' : 'POP2005',
 13     'region' : 'REGION',
 14     'subregion' : 'SUBREGION',
 15     'lon' : 'LON',
 16     'lat' : 'LAT',
 17     'mpoly' : 'MULTIPOLYGON',
 18 }
 19
 20 world_shp = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp'))
 21
 22 def run(verbose=True):
 23     lm = LayerMapping(WorldBorder, world_shp, world_mapping, transform=False, encoding='iso-8859-1')
 24
 25     lm.save(strict=True, verbose=verbose)
```

---

Just an update: 
After going through source code, via stack trace, I figured that I'm unable to access `field_types` propery of `layer` module. So, from python shell, when I access that property, I get the same error:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.gdal import DataSource
>>> ds = DataSource(wshp)
>>> layer = ds[0]
>>> layer.fields
[u'FIPS', u'ISO2', u'ISO3', u'UN', u'NAME', u'AREA', u'POP2005', u'REGION', u'SUBREGION', u'LON', u'LAT']
>>> layer.field_types
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/Envs/rj-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/layer.py", line 153, in field_types
    for i in range(self.num_fields)]
KeyError: 12
```

Now, this is strange, because now I've also removed `mpoly` field from `WorldBorder` model.

---

Update 2:

After digging through the source code, I found out that, `OGDFieldTypes` in my version of gdal, might not have the key 12, as in the source code here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/gdal/field.py.
But it says that keys 12, and 13 will be available for `GDAL 2`, and that is what I've installed. Really seems to be some conflict among libraries now.

I've installed the following libraries:

- geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2
- proj-datumgrid-1.5.tar.gz
- proj-4.8.0.tar.gz
- gdal-2.0.0.tar.gz

And PostGIS version 2.1.5 is installed in Amazon RDS instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that the [version 1.8.2](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) of Django (latest release version at the time of writing) does not support GDAL 2.0.0 field types. The fix for this is in the Django master code branch - but not yet in a release version.

At time of writing you have two options - build Django from the latest source on Github (i.e. upgrade), or downgrade GDAL so that the native code [called by this line](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.2/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/ds.py#L75) cannot return the value `12` as a field type.

Because GDAL 2.0 [can return `12` as a field type](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/67fd4d92f2e7afb604995c6e6846a61bfe3c36fd/gdal/ogr/ogr_core.h#L526), the lookup into [this dictionary](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.2/django/contrib/gis/gdal/field.py#L205) fails with the `KeyError` you see using Django 1.8.2 code.  [On master](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/gdal/field.py#L217), the `dict` contains the right fields for GDAL 2.0 - fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/ffdf507ec0821f0520e315c2e8a6cf231ea3fd5a) (only 9 days old at time of writing!).

---

For completeness - the diagnosis of this fault followed a discussion in the SOPython chat room - a link to the bookmarked conversation [is here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/conversation/gdal-django-compatibility-issue-fix)

***N.B. from the chat*** If you have multiple GDAL versions installed, you may have to add `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH` in django settings file to point to the correct version of `libgdal.so` (or I guess the corresponding `.dll` if you're on Windows)

Comment: Thank you so much @JRichard.. It worked completely fine with GDAL version 1.9.2

Comment: Thank you for the bounty @RohitJain - a nice surprise and very much appreciated :)

Comment: I definitely owed you this for the efforts you put in.. Thanks again :)